# MySql INSERT Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I am new at MySql and i have a problem with my stored procedure. I am trying to create a new sp for insert like:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE 
`NewProc`
(
    IN `PCountryId` binary(16),
    IN `PCountryName` varchar(50),
    IN `PCountryLongitude` float,
    IN `PCountryLatitude` float
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        country
        (
            CountryId,
            CountryName,
            CountryLongitude,
            CountryLatitude
        )
    VALUES
        (
            PCountryId,
            PCountryName,
            PCountryLongitude,
            PCountryLatitude
        )
END;
```

but when i try to run i get this error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 25

Could you please help me to figure out this problem?

Thank you

**EDIT**

When I remove the definer

```
DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
```

it works fine.

Comment: Do you need to delimit the INSERT query with a `);` instead of just `)` on the penultimate line?

Comment: I put a `);` at the end of insert method but still i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The default DEFINER value is CURRENT_USER.

MySQL 5.0 Manual 12.1.9.:

> If you do not have the SUPER
>   privilege, the only legal user value
>   is your own account, either specified
>   literally or by using CURRENT_USER.
>   You cannot set the definer to some
>   other account.

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter inside the stored procedure has to be different from the current delimiter, so you have to write your procedure like this:

*(Disclaimer: I didn't test your procedure so there might be other problems that apply)*

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS NewProc $$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE 
`NewProc`
(
    IN `PCountryId` binary(16),
    IN `PCountryName` varchar(50),
    IN `PCountryLongitude` float,
    IN `PCountryLatitude` float
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        country
        (
            CountryId,
            CountryName,
            CountryLongitude,
            CountryLatitude
        )
    VALUES
        (
            PCountryId,
            PCountryName,
            PCountryLongitude,
            PCountryLatitude
        );
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```